# Regular expression to extract file name from p4 path

Tags: c#, .net, regex, perforce

From path `"//source/project/file.cs#232"`, I need to match `file.cs`

```
Match myMatch = Regex.Match(path, @"(\w+\.\w+)[^/]*$");
```

This would give file.cs in groups[1].

But for paths with dots in the file name, this doesn't work.

```
path "//source/project/file.initial.config.cs#232"
```

How could I modify this to work to give file.initial.config.cs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex -- also into group 1, and assuming the extension can only be letters, numbers or the underscore:

```
.*/((?:.*?\.)+\w+)
```

This could be made more robust, if necessary, with knowledge of the allowable characters and suffixes for file naming, as well as details about the text in which (if) this file name is embedded.  For example, if spaces were not allowed as part of the name

```
.*/((?:\S*?\.)+\w+)
```

or if ONLY letters, digits or the underscore are allowed:

```
.*/((?:\w*?\.)+\w+)
```

If we could be assured that there will be no dots or spaces after the last dot in the sequence, and spaces not allowed in the filename, it could be shortened further to:

```
.*/(\S*\.\w+)
```

to pick up everything between the last "/" and the last "." as well as any word characters after the last "."

etc

Answer (score 1):

A number of non-'/' before '#':

```
/([^/]+)#
```

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to do what you want, or at least give you a better idea of how to achieve it:

```
/(\w+)(?:\..*)(\w{2,3})\#)
```

• example: http://regex101.com/r/wQ9jG2

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply modify your regex from `(\w+\.\w+)[^/]*$` to `(\w+(\.\w+)+)[^/]*$`, to allow multiple occurrences of `.words`?

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex, when you can do it in c# ?

I've created a function for you:

```
public static class FileNameHelper
{
    public static string GetFileNameFromPath(string path, string extWithoutdot = "cs")
    {
        var startIndex = path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
        var stringg = path.Substring(startIndex);
        var remIndex = stringg.LastIndexOf("." + extWithoutdot) + extWithoutdot.Length+1;
        return stringg.Remove(remIndex);
    }
}
```

How to use ?

```
string filename=FileNameHelper.GetFileNameFromPath("//source/project/file.initial.config.cs#232","cs");
```

Remember to use the extension without `.`

See this has a lot of advantage over regex. They are:

1. Its not regex !
2. Its fast and efficient.
3. Its readable and pure c#

**Note:** Don't use regex in c# for trivial things. It's definitely a blow on the performance. First think of ways of achieving it in c#. Regex should be a last resort. Of course, if performance doesn't matter, use whatever !

By the way, mark it as answer if it helps. *I know it'll help :)*

Answer (score 1):

If you're not averse to avoiding regular expressions, you could do this with just a small bit of string manipulation:

```
string mypath = "//source/project/file.initial.config.cs#232";
string filename = GetFileName(mypath);

static string GetFileName(string path)
{
    var pathPieces = path.Split('/').Last().Split('#');
    var filename = pathPieces.Take(pathPieces.Length - 1);
    return String.Join("#", filename);
}
```

Easier, and works with any arbitrary filename (even those with spaces or # characters).

**EDIT**: Now works with filenames with # characters in them, although those are [highly discouraged](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Specification-Names) in Perforce.

Comment: What if the filename contains `#`?

Comment: Those are bad juju, but I've edited my answer to account for them.  Makes it slightly more complex, but not overly so.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=/)[^/]+(?=#)
```

Using lookaround, it matches only the filename.